# Undo changes to javax.persistence.Entity object

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, junit

I have a `User` Entity and respective DAO and impl. One of the method in `UserDAOImpl` is:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {
  ....
  public void editUser(User user) {
      System.out.println("tttt: " + user);
      if ((user.getUserid() == BigInteger.ONE) && !user.getUsername().equalsIgnoreCase("admin")) {
        em.detach(user);
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Cannot change username property for the user admin");
    }
    if ((user.getUserid() == BigInteger.ONE) || !user.getIsActive().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
        em.detach(user);
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Cannot change isactive property for the user admin");
    }
    if ((user.getUserid() == BigInteger.ONE) || !user.getRole().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Administrator")) {
        em.detach(user);
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Cannot change role property for the user admin");
    }
    em.merge(user);
  }
  ....
}
```

Respective Junit code block to test this method is:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:test-context.xml",
                               "classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml"})
@Transactional
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
public class UserDaoTest {
  ....
  @Test
  public void testEditAdminIsactive() {
    User user = userDao.findByUsername("admin");
    user.setIsActive(YNflag.valueOf("No"));
    thrown.expect(IllegalArgumentException.class);
    thrown.expectMessage("Cannot change isactive property for the user admin");
    userDao.editUser(user);
  }

  @Test
  public void testEditAdminRole() {
    User user = userDao.findByUsername("admin");
    user.setRole(UserRole.valueOf("Student"));
    thrown.expect(IllegalArgumentException.class);
    thrown.expectMessage("Cannot change role property for the user admin");
    userDao.editUser(user);
  }

  @Test
  public void testEditAdminUsername() {
    User user = userDao.findByUsername("admin");
    user.setUsername("admin1");
    thrown.expect(IllegalArgumentException.class);
    thrown.expectMessage("Cannot change username property for the user admin");
    userDao.editUser(user);
  }
  ....
}
```

Context file is:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd">

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/test-persistence.xml"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sharedEntityManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fsms?useSSL=false"/>
    <property name="username" value="fsms"/>
    <property name="password" value="fsms"/>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

persistence config is:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0">
  <persistence-unit name="testPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>com.rsa.projects.webtools.sfsms.model.User</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

When I execute Junit tests I get the output as:

> java.lang.AssertionError:
>
> tttt: {Userid: 1, Username: admin, Fullname: Administrator, Isactive: No, Role: Administrator, Address: , Password: fsms, PhoneNumber: 911234567890}
>
> tttt: {Userid: 1, Username: admin, Fullname: Administrator, Isactive: Yes, Role: Student, Address: , Password: fsms, PhoneNumber: 911234567890}
>
> tttt: {Userid: 1, Username: admin1, Fullname: Administrator, Isactive: Yes, Role: Administrator, Address: , Password: fsms, PhoneNumber: 911234567890}
>
> testEditAdminRole(com.rsa.projects.webtools.sfsms.test.UserDaoTest) 
>   Time elapsed: 0.043 sec  <<< FAILURE!
>
> Expected: (an instance of java.lang.IllegalArgumentException and exception with message a string containing "Cannot change role
>   property for the user admin")
>        but: exception with message a string containing "Cannot change role property for the user admin" message was "Cannot change isactive
>   property for the user admin"

This is because whatever set methods called in `testEditAdminUsername` and `testEditAdminIsactive` are available in `testEditAdminRole` also.

How to rollback the changes done to the `User` entity object before throwing an exception in `editUser` method?

Comment: In your method `userDao.findByUsername("admin");` are you forcing your hibernate session to get the data from the database, or is it allowed to rely on memory? You may need to call a `session.refresh(entity)` to make sure it's not still using the same `User` entity it has stored in memory

Comment: Tried in 2 different ways first adding em.refresh(user) later adding @Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW). Still the same problem.

public void editUser(User user) {
   ....
    if ((user.getUserid() == BigInteger.ONE) && !user.getUsername().equalsIgnoreCase("admin")) {
        em.refresh(user);
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Cannot change username property for the user admin");
    } ......
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public List<User> getAllUsersOrderedByUsername() {...}

Comment: My bad. My condition in if loop is wrong which caused all the wrong assumptions. Wrong question. Please ignore.